# Catching non-existent XML nodes before "object not set" error

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I have something similar to the XML below. I'm parsing it using Linq in C#, and it works great, until we get to a product which doesn't have a `type`.

```
<productList>
    <product>
        <type>
            <colour>red</colour>
        </type>
        <name>First</name>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>Second</name>
    </product>
</productList>
```

I'm trying to access the `colour` element under `type`, but when the code reaches a `product` which doesn't have the `type` element, I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Here's the code I'm using to access it at the moment. Things have got a little complicated with the attempts I've tried to solve this.

```
productColour = products.Element("type").Descendants().FirstOrDefault() == null ? string.Empty : products.Element("type").Descendants().FirstOrDefault().Value,
```

I know the `colour` element is always the first underneath `type`, so I can use `.FirstOrDefault()`, but I still get the same error using this code.

Can anyone point me towards the right direction? I've also tried casting to a string, and also having: `?? " "` at the end, all to no avail so far.

**Edit:** Thanks to @anthony-pegram, it looks like the issue is that I'm always trying to grab the descendants, even if the parent element doesn't exist. So it looks like I need to check the parent element before grabbing the child - can anyone point me in a direction for this?

Comment: When you say `Elements("type").Descendants()`, and there is no "type" element, you are going to get an error. You need to deal with the missing element *before* you query its descedants. Your attempt so far is to deal with missing descendants, but that's after your problem as already rendered its ugly head.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - would you have any idea how to go about this using Linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elements()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) wiil return an IEnumerable. If the element does not exist, IEnumerable will just be empty and calling Elements again on it will not product a null reference exception.  The code below should pull the colour from under a product\type element without throwing a null reference exception. If colour or type do not exist, it will return a null.

```
(string)product.Elements("type").Elements("colour").FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: using "Elements" rather than "Element"?

Comment: That may be the best edit you could have made. That appears to have worked nicely - thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I would use XPath here

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var colour = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//product/type/colour");
if(colour!=null)
{
    var val = colour.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using an Attribute instead?

```
<productList>
    <product type="color-red">
        <name>First</name>
    </product>
    <product type="none">
        <name>Second</name>
    </product>
</productList>
```

No chance of returning a null variable, as the type attribute can have a default string value. I also think this is more tidy, but that's personal preference.

You could also do `<product color="red" />` etc.

Comment: It certainly is more tidy, but I unfortunately don't have any control over the XML source in this scenario. Thanks anyway, though!